# How to make emacs running in daemon mode read my bashrc before start?

Tags: emacs-daemon, system-environment

I run Emacs in the daemon mode as a user's systemd unit. However it won't read my environment variables. How to make it import my .bashrc first?
I have multiple paths added in there and want to be able to use them in Emacs (but I don't want to maintain both .bashrc and .emacs by adding them to exec-path).

Comment: Can you please tell use more about what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Nsukami_, I've updated the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably looking for the package exec-path-from-shell. Once it's installed, put this in your .emacs:

```
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```

for emacs to read .bashrc on startup. That way  you won't have to maintain paths in two places.

Comment: This does not seem to work when I put it in my `init.el` file. Is the `.emacs` file a requirement? (That would make it hard to VCS my `~/.emacs.d`

Comment: Did you first install the package `exec-path-from-shell`?

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted to put Emacs' socket into my encrypted `$HOME`, I had to put the definition `TMPDIR="$HOME/tmp;export TMPDIR"` in my `$HOME/.profile` file, so an early shell would see the definition and pass it in Emacs' `ENVIRONMENT`.