# Why is exec-path different in emacsclient / emacsserver than in emacs?

Tags: emacsclient, path, exec-path

I am trying to run an identical emacsserver setup as the emacs I normally use.

I am having issues because the emacsserver has a different `exec-path` variable when it starts than when normal `emacs` does.

To start emacsserver I am using:
`/usr/bin/emacs --daemon` in a systemd script.  To start emacs normally I just type `emacs`

emacsserver (which I connect to by typing emacsclient`) has the following value for`exec-path`:

```
    exec-path is a variable defined in `C source code'.
    Its value is
    ("PATH" "/usr/local/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/bin" "/usr/lib/emacs/24.5/x86_64-linux-gnu")
```

Whereas "normal" emacs has the full path I normally use:

```
exec-path is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is
("/usr/local/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/bin" "/usr/games" "/usr/local/games" "/snap/bin" "/bin" "/usr/local/bin" "/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/opt/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64/bin" "/opt/node-v4.2.1-li\
nux-x64/bin/node" "/home/optonox/.npm-global/bin" "/usr/local/mongodb/bin" "/snap/bin" "/bin" "/usr/local/bin" "/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/opt/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64/bin" "/opt/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/optono\
x/.npm-global/bin" "/usr/local/mongodb/bin" "/usr/lib/emacs/24.5/x86_64-linux-gnu")
```

Why is this happening / can I start it normally somehow?

Answer (score 4):

`exec_path` is initialized from the `EMACSPATH` and `PATH` environment variables. Emacs also adds the directory containing the emacs binary to the end. This is done at startup by `init_callproc_1` in `callproc.c` (http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/callproc.c#n1466)

The `systemd.exec` man page has a section about the environment variables it sets whenever it starts a process. Here's what it has to say about `PATH`:

```
   $PATH
       Colon-separated list of directories to use when launching executables. Systemd uses a fixed value of
       /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin.
```

Since that matches very well with your `exec-path`, the only real mystery is why you're ending up with the string `"PATH"` in there; that's kinda weird.

Comment: I see so the real fix is to try to somehow set the path in systemd.  Because that seems hard, I wonder, is there an easy way to set the path in emacs? It seems like there should be an argument passed in.

Comment: You can customize `exec-path` to whatever value you want, or you can change the environment that systemd launches emacs in. For example, you could add `Environment="EMACSPATH=/foo/bar:…"` to your systemd unit file.

Comment: I'm assuming `EMACSPATH` is just an example variable correct? I would really want to set `PATH` correct?

Comment: No. Emacs will use the values from both `EMACSPATH` and `PATH`, as you can see in the source code that I linked to. I recommend setting `EMACSPATH` unless you specifically need to set `PATH` for some reason you haven't mentioned in your question. It's safer, because only Emacs will use it.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, new answer...

I was in the same position, and met success following the advice in [1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18488/how-to-make-emacs-running-in-daemon-mode-read-my-bashrc-before-start) to install the package
`exec-path-from-shell` and add to my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

```
(require 'exec-path-from-shell)
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```

For me, this solution was necessitated by not having any other means than `systemd` to get an `emacs --daemon` to reliably persist between between (dropped) sessions.

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly!